# NodeJS - Is it safe to send Json Web Token(JWT) in register verification email?

Tags: node.js, email, server

My node.js server uses Json Web Token(JWT) and passport.js for authentication. After the user registered, the server will send a verification email to the user, and normally there should be a token generated in the verification link for safety. But since my site is usgin jwt, can I just send jwt as part of the verification link in the email?

i.e. the verification link would be http://example.com/verification/some-jwt

So as long as the user gets the email, he also gets jwt and can store in browser for future authentication.

Is this a good practice?

Comment: did you come to a decision regarding your question, which approach did you go with? I have the same question.

Comment: @Teebo I've posted a solution, please check.

Comment: I read the solution and I can't seem to understand, does it mean that I can use a module like https://passwordless.net/? If not do you mind sending any links or a brief walk through? thanks

Comment: @Teebo No, a module is not required. You can implement the generation, check and deletion of the token yourself. Afterall a token is just a randomly generated string, and is safe to be put as part of the url.

Comment: okay now I see, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brody mentioned, a better solution is to email a 'one-time token' link. On clicking on that link, cookie will be verified and JWT will be returned.

Here, we can just store the JWT in browser's local storage - don't really need cookie.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.  You don't really want to mix email and browser information together.

A better solution might be to email a 'one-time token' link that will load the JWT into a cookie when the link is clicked the first time.  This will allow your web site to set the browser cookie with the JWT.

The risk is that your token can be *got at* for an extended period of time.

Comment: Thanks! One-time token sounds works well. But since I'm using jwt, shouldn't I avoid using cookie?